# SSIS OData source works in Visual Studio 2017 but fails when run in Azure Data Factory

Tags: visual-studio, azure, ssis, odata, etl

When I test the OData source connection in my host with Visual Studio 2017, the connection is ok.
However, when I push the SSIS package into the Azure Data Factory and I run it, it fails.
The only error message that I receive is:

```
{
    "SsisDBOperationGuid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "SsisDBOperationId": YYYYYY,
    "OperationErrorMessages": "4/11/2019 9:54:21 AM +00:00 : Tarea Flujo de datos:Error: The connection \"Connection\" cannot be found. Verify that the connection manager has a connection with that name.\r\n\n4/11/2019 9:54:21 AM +00:00 : Tarea Flujo de datos:Error: Origen OData failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801A.\r\n\n4/11/2019 9:54:21 AM +00:00 : Tarea Flujo de datos:Error: One or more component failed validation.\r\n\n",
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "integrationRuntime1 (West Europe)",
    "executionDuration": 10197
}
```

The main error message is:

> Error: The connection \"Connection\" cannot be found. Verify that the connection manager has a connection with that name.

Comment: You probably need to install it into the Azure SSIS runtime. Is this a MS component or a third party component? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup

Comment: I am using a [normal OData component](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/integration-services/data-flow/odata-source?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Did you download and install it as this link says https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3220/using-the-odata-source-in-sql-server-integration-services/ ? If so you need to do the same on the Azure SSIS runtime.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed [this component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) and it works fine in my computer. Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i think the cause is the language difference between local machine and azure data factory.

Comment: The problem is most likely that you haven’t installed it in data factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error cause is the difference between the Visual studio default language and the azure language. Try changing the connection name from the package XML *(just open the .dtsx file with a text editor)*. You can refer to the following post for more details:

- [The connection "Connection" cannot be found. Verify that the connection manager has a connection with that name.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8d524f0-d373-47d1-b239-424b26ac59a7/the-connection-quotconnectionquot-cannot-be-found-verify-that-the-connection-manager-has-a?forum=sqlintegrationservices)